# Java - Cannot add export from java.base

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, illegalaccessexception

I've modified openjdk14's module jdk.jartool and renamed it (So when I deploy a jar for clients to use, the default jdk.jartool in their jdk won't take place instead).

Now, when I try to run the module, I get the following issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.security.tools.kmsjarsigner.Main (in module jdk.kmsjartool) cannot access class sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to module jdk.kmsjartool
    at jdk.kmsjartool/sun.security.tools.kmsjarsigner.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:92)
```

I've added from Intellij the following JVM arguments:
[image: JVM Arguments]

Now, as you can see, I've added exports and opens to `java.base/sun.secruity.util`, yet I still get `IllegalAccessError` when I try to use it.

Can you help me find out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: try using `jdk.kmsjartool` in the JVM arg instead of `ALL-UNNAMED`. `ALL-UNNAMED` is for unnamed modules and your moduke is named.

Comment: @dan1st Thanks for your time. I did try doing that, but I still get the same issue. Any other ideas, maybe?